# Repeat android animation before its end

Tags: android, animation, repeat

I have a basic animation that make a picture grow and fade, syntax is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <scale
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
   android:fromXScale="1.0"
   android:toXScale="4.0"
   android:fromYScale="1.0"
   android:toYScale="4.0"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%"
   android:fillAfter="true"
   android:duration="2500"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:repeatMode="restart" />
  <alpha    
   android:fromAlpha="1.0"    
   android:toAlpha="0.0"    
   android:duration="2500"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:repeatMode="restart"/>  

</set>
```

Then I call it like that

```
    ImageView circleImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_loader);
    Animation pulseAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pulse_animation);
    circleImage.startAnimation(pulseAnimation);
```

Everything is working as expected but I would like to repeat that animation before its end. Let's say I want to repeat the animation each second even if it takes 2.5 seconds to play.

What is the proper way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

create animation file name as progress_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/animation_one"
        android:duration="350"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/animation_two"
        android:duration="350"/>
     <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/animation_three" 
        android:duration="350"/> 
    <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/animation_four"
         android:duration="350"/> 

</animation-list>
```

Here drawable files are different images of same image after applying animation.

Apply this animation into your ImageView as below :

```
ImageView ivProgress = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.iv_progress);

    // Set the background of the image - In this case an animation
    // (/res/anim folder)
    ivProgress.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.progress_animation);

    // Get the image background and attach the AnimationDrawable to it.
    progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ivProgress.getBackground();
    progressAniation.start();
```